# Can I prevent Windows 10 from grabbing Win+L in VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, keyboard-shortcuts

My VirtualBox client system (specifically, its window manager, i3) has <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as a common shortcut, but I can't use it because Windows grabs it and interprets it, instalocking the system. However, at least some other shortcuts, such as <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> (quick launch bar items), are handed to the client instead. Can I enforce this behavior for all Windows keyboard shortcuts?

I can change the keyboard shortcuts for either Windows or i3 instead, of course, but I'd rather not have to.

Comment: This only should happen if VirtualBox is the active window, since the host OS would only pick it up, if it was not the active Window.

Comment: That's just it. Win+L is picked up by Windows, even though VirtualBox is active. This doesn't happen with e.g. Win+#.

Comment: I use VMWare Workstation exclusively.  So if that is happening then that is a problem with VirtualBox.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> Windows-lock function with a registry edit.

You'd need to add the following reg key and value:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System] "DisableLockWorkstation"=dword:00000001
```

See [this guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disableenable-lock-workstation-functionality-windows-l/) for more details and a download for a .reg file to to add the key automatically.

Comment: I'm actually looking for a way to change the priority of the Windows shortcut to be below that of VirtualBox, not to disable it completely.